# Всем привет! Есть проблема с unity3d

Tags: c#, unity3d

Впервые сел за этот движок и нашел скрипт для свободной камеры, так вот мне нужно её ограничить по осям z, y, и x. Тк я не хочу что-бы объект вылетал за заданные мной рамки. Сама камера:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraFly : MonoBehaviour {

    public float mouseSensitivity = 3.0f;
    public float speed = 2.0f;
    private Vector3 transfer;

    public float minimumX = -360F;
    public float maximumX = 360F;
    public float minimumY = -60F;
    public float maximumY = 60F;
    float rotationX = 0F;
    float rotationY = 0F;
    Quaternion originalRotation;


    void Start() {
        originalRotation = transform.rotation;
    }

    void Update() {
        // Движения мыши -> Вращение камеры
        rotationX += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSensitivity;
        rotationY += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSensitivity;
        rotationX = ClampAngle (rotationX, minimumX, maximumX);
        rotationY = ClampAngle (rotationY, minimumY, maximumY);
        Quaternion xQuaternion = Quaternion.AngleAxis (rotationX, Vector3.up);
        Quaternion yQuaternion = Quaternion.AngleAxis (rotationY, Vector3.left);
        transform.rotation = originalRotation * xQuaternion * yQuaternion;
        // перемещение камеры
        transfer = transform.forward * Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        transfer += transform.right * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        transform.position += transfer * speed * Time.deltaTime;
    }

    public static float ClampAngle (float angle, float min, float max)
    {
        if (angle < -360F) angle += 360F;
        if (angle > 360F) angle -= 360F;
        return Mathf.Clamp (angle, min, max);
    }

}
```

По поводу ограничения обзора все понятно, тут имеются публичные переменные класса. Хотелось бы что-то вроде `если позиция.камера.х = нужное значение по x => двигать камеру в нужное значение по x`. Сделать бы что-то вроде тупика. Буду рад любой помощи.

Comment: А сами вы пробовали что-то сделать?

Comment: Ну я рыскал по док-ии по unity и что-то не разобрался.

Comment: Тогда вам нужно нанять программиста, к сожалению, здесь не пишут код за вас.

Comment: Я просто думал может какую страничку почитать скинут может быть из той же самой док-ии, но ок, буду сам тогда разбирать все это.

Comment: Алгоритмически вы в конце вопроса все вроде бы верно расписали, осталось только запрограммировать.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker: ну что же Вы сразу на человека накинулись? ТС помощи и напутствия просит, а не того, чтобы за него код написали

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, да вроде не кидался я, лишь спросил, сделал ли человек что-то сам или пришел сюда с скопипасченным кодом камеры. Сама задача элементарна и посильна даже новичку в юнити, вопрос лишь в желании :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте этот код:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraFly : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float mouseSensitivity = 3.0f;
    public float speed = 2.0f;
    private Vector3 transfer;

    public float minimumX = -360F;
    public float maximumX = 360F;
    public float minimumY = -60F;
    public float maximumY = 60F;
    float rotationX = 0F;
    float rotationY = 0F;
    Quaternion originalRotation;

    const float minCamX = -400; // минимальная позиция по X
    const float maxCamX = 400; // максимальная позиция по X

    const float minCamY = -100; // минимальная позиция по Y
    const float maxCamY = 100; // максимальная позиция по Y

    const float minCamZ = -400; // минимальная позиция по Z
    const float maxCamZ = 400; // максимальная позиция по Z

    void Start()
    {
        originalRotation = transform.rotation;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // Движения мыши -> Вращение камеры
        rotationX += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSensitivity;
        rotationY += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSensitivity;
        rotationX = ClampAngle(rotationX, minimumX, maximumX);
        rotationY = ClampAngle(rotationY, minimumY, maximumY);
        Quaternion xQuaternion = Quaternion.AngleAxis(rotationX, Vector3.up);
        Quaternion yQuaternion = Quaternion.AngleAxis(rotationY, Vector3.left);
        transform.rotation = originalRotation * xQuaternion * yQuaternion;
        // перемещение камеры
        transfer = transform.forward * Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        transfer += transform.right * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        transform.position += transfer * speed * Time.deltaTime;

        RestrictionCam();
    }

    public static float ClampAngle(float angle, float min, float max)
    {
        if (angle < -360F) angle += 360F;
        if (angle > 360F) angle -= 360F;
        return Mathf.Clamp(angle, min, max);
    }

    // Ограничение камеры
    void RestrictionCam()
    {
        Vector3 cl = transform.position;

        cl.x = Mathf.Clamp(cl.x, minCamX, maxCamX);
        cl.y = Mathf.Clamp(cl.y, minCamY, maxCamY);
        cl.z = Mathf.Clamp(cl.z, minCamZ, maxCamZ);

        transform.position = cl;
    }

}
```

Comment: Начал уже свои костыли пилить, понимаю что что-то не так))) Спасибо что скинули, все работает отлично!